# MS Word 2010 macro to renumber pages within the footer of all sections.

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

My problems is that I also have a divider page which originally I provided -1 in the page field to get the appropriate count.  Could you please advise how I can manipulate the macro to take this back into account...

Here is the macro

```
Sub Main()
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 0 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
        ActiveDocument.Sections(i).Footers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).PageNumbers.RestartNumberingAtSection = False
        ActiveDocument.Sections(i).Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).PageNumbers.RestartNumberingAtSection = False
        ActiveDocument.Sections(i).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.RestartNumberingAtSection = False
    Next i
End Sub
```